# Is it possible to remove empty query string parameters in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to test an endpoint using jmeter, that has a copule of query string parameters, one of which is optional, loading the values from a CSV file. The problem is, can I avoid sending the query string parameter if I don't have a value for it?

Answer (score 0):

It is but it will require some [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) coding

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which query string you want to modify (or according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) if you want to apply the approach to more than one request)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def newData = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()

   0.upto(sampler.getArguments().size() - 1, { idx ->
        def arg = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(idx)
        if (!arg.getValue().equals('')) {
            newData.addArgument(arg)
        }
   })

   sampler.setArguments(newData)
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will be executed before the HTTP Request sampler and will remove all arguments which don't have their respective values